# How do you convert "Month dd, yyyy" to yyyy-mm-dd in Go?

Tags: go, time

I need to convert for example "April 20, 1996" to 1996-04-20. I have tried the following code but I have a feeling that I am doing it in reverse somehow.

```
func main() {
    value  := "April 20, 1996"
    layout := "January 1, 1996"
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
    mydate, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-07-08")
    fmt.Println("time:", mydate.Format("April 20, 1996 (MST)"))
}
```

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) and also mentioned in the answer, the reference time is `01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700`. Did you see the pattern? It's nicely ordered from `01` to `07`. Additional "rule", when expressing hour in `24-hour style`, replace `03` with `15` which is another representation of `03 PM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to parse the time using the input layout and then print it using the output layout. The layout always specifies how the reference time (Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006) would look in the given format. I think this is what you want:

```
func main() {
    value := "April 20, 1996"
    layout := "January 2, 2006"
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println("time:", t.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

See https://golang.org/pkg/time/ for more information.